# SocketIO no trabaja en componentes de otras rutas en REACT

Tags: reactjs, socket, react-router-dom, socket.io, websocket

Tengo un componente llamado NAV este componente es estático en la aplicación, en ese componente manejo la escucha del socket.on para almacenar la información de notificación, si hay una ruta que no contiene el socket funciona normal, pero cuando introduje el socket en un componente dentro de una ruta, deja de funcionar el socket que estaba dentro del componente NAV, a juro debo repetir el código de socket.on del componente NAV para que pueda llegar la información otra vez, esto es mala practica porque no se debería repetir el código esto me pasa con 5 componentes en rutas distintas, pero no se como hacer para que no pase esto

Probé en hacer un componente que cubra todos los componentes dentro de las rutas y ahí manejar la información de los sockets pero no me funciono

**ESTE ES EL CODIGO QUE TENGO EN EL SOCKET EN EL SERVIDOR**

```
socket.on("received event", async (id, productID) => {
  if (id || productID) {
    let product;

    if (productID !== undefined)
      product = await Product.findById(productID);

    const user = getUser(id ? id : product.owner);

    if (user.length > 0)
      user.map((user) => io.to(user.socketId).emit("received event"));
  }
});
```

**ESTE ES EL CODIGO QUE TENGO EN EL NAV PERO LO TENGO QUE REPETIR EN CADA RUTA QUE INTEGRE EL SOCKET**

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("received event", async () => {
    await searchNotifications();
  });

  return () => socket.off();
});
```

**ESTE ES EL COMPONENTE PRINCIPAL**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <LoadingZone>
      <Nav /> // AQUI ESTA EL SOCKET EL CODIGO DE ARRIBA QUE SE REPITE
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="/report" element={<PrivateRoute><Report /></PrivateRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/messages" element={<PrivateRoute><Messages /></PrivateRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/notifications" element={<PrivateRoute><Notifications /></PrivateRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/help/*" element={<Help />} />
        <Route path="/post/information/*" element={<Post />} /> // EL SOCKET QUE ESTA EN EL NAV NO AFECTA A ESTE
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
      <PopupWindow/>
    </LoadingZone>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Se supone que debería seguir tomando el socket del NAV ya que no depende de ninguna ruta pero no lo hace, el socket principal lo tengo en un archivo separado en el cual puedo acceder a el en diferentes componente. Pero este es mi problema

**Se supone que debería seguir tomando el socket del NAV ya que no depende de ninguna ruta pero no lo hace**

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el código comentando qué es lo que estás haciendo y señalando donde tienes el problema? Es dificil ayudarte sin saber realmente qué estás haciendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por estar pendiente ya lo coloco

Comment: ¿Y cuál es tu componente principal? Por lo que veo necesitas data de un usuario, ¿asumo que esta data está en un componente principal? De ser así puedes crear esta función en ese componente y compartirla a través de tus rutas usando props.

Comment: Listo ya agregue lo que falta

Comment: Me podrías decir tu opinión?

Comment: ¿El código de tu Socket está en el componente Nav? Podrías sacarlo y colocarlo en en tu App y pasarlo como prop si lo necesitas en todos los componentes.